# Convert prediction values back to original scale (forecasting with python fbProphet)

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

My original data is non-stationary so I did a differencing to make stationary. Now that I've forecasted on the stationary data I am trying to figure out how to convert the forecast back to original scale (non-stationary data). I am forecasting with fbProphet in Python.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ds': ['2017-01-01', '2017-04-01', '2017-07-01', '2017-10-01',
                          '2018-01-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-10-01',
                          '2019-01-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-10-01',
                          '2020-01-01', '2020-04-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-10-01'],
                  'y':[4059381873.720, 3936022899.570, 3961640668.380, 4242659441.670,
                       5977815298.110, 5667693395.900, 5742857936.020, 5987400072.220,
                       6055073805.400, 5890612335.240, 6005389778.200, 6395789261.300,
                       6585582542.840,5185450083.230,6138492942.310,6581388293.000]})

# differencing on y col for stationary data
df['y'] = df['y'].diff().dropna()

# prophet model
m = Prophet()
m.fit(inc_stationary)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=4, freq='QS')
forecast = m.predict(future)

# convert ds col to datetime
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
# merge inc and forecast for new df
comb = pd.merge(df, forecast, on='ds', how='outer')
```

comb dataframe merges original data (df) and forecast. I want to convert forecast (yhat) back to original scale so I can plot y and yhat.